# Can I not display the password a data form when using @Html.PasswordFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the framework MVC5 - ASP.NET and made a login form using @Html.TextBox, @Html.Password.

With Chrome's DevTools>Network>Form Data,
Password and ID is displayed. I'd like to hide them.
Is there method/any feature MVC provides to hide password when it is delivered from view to controller?

Thank you.

[image - data form <- I'd like to hide this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyeGP.png)

-- Login Form Code is below --

```
@Html.TextBox("USERID", (string)@Model.USERID, new { @placeholder = "Username", @id = "login_id" })
@Html.Password("USERPSWD", (string)@Model.USERPSWD, new { @placeholder = "Password", @id = "login_pw", autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: When input type is password, the value is masked. rite ? What else you want ?

Comment: That's chromes feature to debug the issues. It works the same for all the web sites and web applications. MVC can not do anything about it.

Comment: I'd like to encrypt password when it is delivered from view to controller!

Comment: So it is not possible to hide the ID/password in a data form?

Comment: @Jiwon use SSL?

Comment: No that's not possible. If someone needs to hack your password they don't need to look into the developers tools. They are lot other ways hackers use for stealing your data

Comment: What's the purpose of hiding login details when sending from view to controller?

Comment: @JiwonB you don't need to encrypt the password. You need to use HTTPS, which will encrypt all traffic including the password. You aren't sending login details from the view to the controller. You are sending login details from the *browser* to a controller action. The view is used to generate the HTML displayed on the browser

Comment: @JiwonB and no, you can't *not* use HTTPS. HTTPS is the only thing that ensures intermediaries can't hijack the connection, read the content or inject their own scripts (including keyloggers) to the page. Intermediaries like the a coffee shop's router for example.

Comment: @JiwonB hiding the contents of the password field from browser malware is the browser's job. Browsers offer extra protection for password fields. It's quite OK for the browser's dev tools to display contents to the user that just entered them. Those contents won't be visible to any other code though

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is SSL/HTTPS. It's used to encrypt the data between the client and server. Depending on how you're using the dev tools, it's likely you're looking at the data before it's being sent to the controller

You can enable your application to use HTTPS in a development environment, but your browser will likely warn you that the certificate is not trusted. If you plan on deploying the application, you will need to purchase an SSL certificate against your production domain.

Comment: There's no need to purchase an SSL certificate, Let's Encrypt is free. ASP.NET Core documentation explains how to handle certificates during development to avoid warnings too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Although Let's Encrypt provide a free Domain Validation (DV) certificate, they do not provide Organisation Validation (OS) or Extended Validation (EV) variants. It's entirely possible they aren't required, but I wouldn't recommend a free service without knowing.

Comment: Which offer nothing on top of DVs. That's why Troy Hunt, Scott Helme and others support them. The OS/EV vendors have tried to scare people with the result that ... they lose customers even faster. Check [On The (Perceived) Value of EV Certs, Commercial CAs, Phishing and Let's Encrypt](https://www.troyhunt.com/on-the-perceived-value-ev-certs-cas-phishing-lets-encrypt/) and [Are EV certificates worth the paper they're written on?](https://scotthelme.co.uk/are-ev-certificates-worth-the-paper-theyre-written-on/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Again that's not strictly true. I would take a look at this post regarding the subject: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90972/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-lets-encrypt-for-a-websites-ssl-certificates. I know from experience that some budget hosting services make it extremely difficult to import 3rd party certificates. It could be worth a small charge to simplify the process instead of wasting your time refusing to pay anything.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I solved this problem with RSA encryption!